# Telegram API get updates in a channel

Tags: python-3.x, api, telegram

I have a telegram bot , i have a code in python the publish links to different channels.

Is there any way to know who press the link , i tried with get_updates , but it only shows messages.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Text and InlineKeyboardButton link clicks are not tracked by Telegram. You can try using third-party services (url-shorteners) to track your links.

*NOTE: this feature is not declared by Telegram. In my experience, Telegram did not send Update about the same actions.*